# Remove derived type from entity using Table Per Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, table-per-type

I have a person, who is also an government employee, who works as a teacher. I have 3 tables to contain the information for each type this person is. `Person`, `GovernmentEmployee`, and `Teacher`.

Now this person leaves their job as a teacher, but still remains as a government employee.

How can I remove the derived `Teacher` type, but retain all the other data in `Person` and `GovernmentEmployee` ?

I can obviously create a new `GovernmentEmployee` entity, and manually copy the data, but I'm wondering whether Entity Framework has a method that will allow me to do this just be removing the derived `Teacher` type ?

If this is not possible, or bad practise, it would be very useful to explain why.

Comment: What is the inheritance hierarchy? `Person > GovernmentEmployee > Teacher`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A `Teacher` is a `GovernmentEmployee` is a `Person`.

Comment: urgh, more reasons not to use EF. it looks like EF tries to put all the info in a single table, so changing jobs isn't simple. but if you have three tables perhaps yours isnt setup that way?

Comment: It might not be the best example I confess, as a person 'has a' job, but hopefully it gets the point across. I could use some SQL to delete the `Teacher` outside of EF, but that doesn't seem the right way to do it.